# How to set recurring events IsReminder date and time using Apex

Tags: apex, event, lightning-events, recurring

I am trying to create a recurring event which is a full day event and event will create every week and I want to set a reminder before 15 min of the event starts.
Below are the lines which I am using.

```
singleEvent.IsRecurrence = true;
singleEvent.ActivityDate = System.today();
singleEvent.RecurrenceStartDateTime = System.today();
singleEvent.RecurrenceEndDateOnly = System.today()+18;
singleEvent.RecurrenceType = 'RecursWeekly';
singleEvent.RecurrenceInterval = 1; 
singleEvent.RecurrenceDayofWeekMask = 2;
singleEvent.IsAllDayEvent = true;
singleEvent.DurationInMinutes = 1440;
singleEvent.IsReminderSet = true;
singleEvent.ReminderDateTime = ???;
```

My concern is what values I need to give in `ReminderDateTime` for setting the reminder before 15 min of the event?

I am creating the events in Salesforce lightning.

Answer (score 3):

After creating your recurring event, you'll want to query a list of child events that were created as a result, then you can set the ReminderDateTime on each individual child record (don't forget to also set IsReminderSet), something like:

```
Event[] recurrentEvents = [SELECT StartDateTime FROM Event WHERE RecurrenceActivityId = :singleEvent.Id];
for(Event recurrentEvent: recurrentEvents) {
  recurrentEvent.IsReminderSet = true;
  recurrentEvent.ReminderDateTime = recurrentEvent.StartDateTime.addMinutes(-15);
}
update recurrentEvents;
```

Comment: Thanks, It's worked as expected.